# Possible to match mutliple received messages in Akka FSM

Tags: scala, akka

Is it possible to match multiple messages in a single case/Event using the Akka FSM Event functionality. Meaning I would like to collapse two events into a single one.

```
case Event(response : GoodResponse, session:CustomerSession) =>
case Event(response : Timeout, session:CustomerSession) =>
case Event(response : Rejected, session:CustomerSession) =>
```

become something like

```
case Event(response : GoodResponse, session:CustomerSession) =>
case Event(response : Timeout || response : Rejected , session:CustomerSession) =>
```

Both error cases call the same handling function and return the same result so I would prefer to advertise that fact via the Event handling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply have `Timeout` and `Rejected` implement the same Trait and match on that Trait.

If as you write in the comment you can't change the types/implementation of Timeout and Rejected, you might be able to use a case, that just ignores the type. This should work, if you have handled all other cases before. I would look like

```
case Event(response : GoodResponse, session:CustomerSession) =>
case Event(response : _, session:CustomerSession) =>
```

I'm not sure if I have the _ syntax right, but something along this line should work.

Comment: This almost works, but I'm using an ADT that is outside of my control. They all implement the same underlying trait. I could potentially pimp them using tagged types. If no one else has a better answer I'll accept this one, since it is what first came to mind for me.

Comment: I think that is the best we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define a custom extractor like this:

```
object RejectedOrTimeout{
  def unapply(value:Any) = {
    if (value.isInstanceOf[Rejected] || value.isInstanceOf[Timeout]) Some(value) 
    else None
  }
}
```

And then use it in your match statement like this:

```
case Event(RejectedOrTimeout(response), session:CustomerSession) =>
```